When launching a 5250 emulator from RDi how do I get it to use my saved .hod file? Or save configurations
I use RDi to connect to several different systems, many times a production server and a test server, I like to distinguish them with changing the color theme. But every time I launch from objects in RDi, it seems to launch a default one. Does anyone know how/where I can save preferred setting per connection?
